# Selection only one child that match the Parent Name xpath 1.0

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0, xpath-1.0

So I have this XMl file to filter using XPATH.

```
    `<Root>
        <Program Name="PGM_Name1">
        <ProgFileName>200</ProgFileName>
        <ProgName>PGM_Name</ProgName>
        <NcJob>
         <Name>Job1</Name>
      <NcJob>
      </Program>
<Program Name="PGM_Name">
      <ProgFileName>200</ProgFileName>
      <ProgName>PGM_Name1</ProgName>
      <NcJob>
         <Name>Job2</Name>
      <NcJob>
      </Program>
<Program Name="PGM_Name2">
      <ProgFileName>201</ProgFileName>
      <ProgName>PGM_Name2</ProgName>
      <NcJob>
         <Name>Job3</Name>
      <NcJob>
      </Program>
</Root>`
```

And what I want is to select only one element `<Name>` from each `<Program>` parent.
The struggle is how to match the `<ProgFileName>` on each `<Program>` element.

The Context node that I need to use is `<Name>` 
So I cannot do anything similar to `//NcJob/Name != ./preceding::Program/NcJob/Name`

Any help here?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: ancestor::Program[1][not(ProgFileName = preceding-sibling::Program/ProgFileName)]  This will work from the Name node.  It this evaluates to true, the Name node is first name node in Programs with the same ProgFileName.

Comment: Why not //program//name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following XPath expression which respect the conditions you've stated :

```
//Name[preceding::ProgName[1]/text()=ancestor::Program[1]/@Name]
```

Output : Job3